# local variable 'Postive_Points' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am using jypyter notebook and my code keeps giving same error for some inputs:

```
file0 = open("stopwords.txt", "r")
StopWords=list(file0.read().split('\n'))

file = open("positive-words.txt", "r")
positive_words=list(file.read().split('\n'))

file2 = open("negative-words.txt", "r")
negative_words=list(file2.read().split('\n'))


def evaluate(string,Positive_Points=0,Negative_Points=0):
    string=list(string.split())
###    print(string)
    Output=[]
    for s in string:
        s=s.lower()
        if s not in StopWords:
            Output.append(s)
###    print(Output)
    for word in Output:
###        print(word)
        if word in positive_words:
            Postive_Points+=1
        elif word in negative_words:
            Negative_Points+=1
    return Positive_Points,Negative_Points
```

next cell in jupyter notebook:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
result = evaluate("Everything is nice")
lables = ['Positive','Negative']
colors = ['blue','red']
plt.pie(result, labels=lables, colors=colors, startangle=90, autopct='%.1f%%')
plt.show()
```

This is how the error looks like:

UnboundLocalError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
 in

```
      1 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
      2 
----> 3 result = evaluate("Everything is nice")
      4 lables = ['Positive','Negative']
      5 colors = ['blue','red']
```

in evaluate(string, Positive_Points, Negative_Points)

```
     21 ###        print(word)
     22         if word in positive_words:
---> 23             Postive_Points+=1
     24         elif word in negative_words:
     25             Negative_Points+=1
```

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'Postive_Points' referenced before assignment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just misspelled `Positive_Points` in line 23.